# NserviceBus rollback after sending

Tags: nservicebus

Hi I have with this code

```
 SendMessageToMyQueue();
UpdateStatusInDbThatMessageWasSent();
```

that sometimes message is processed before status is updated which I would like to avoid.

My question is if I wrap that two line with a transaction like this:

```
using(var tr = new TransactionScope())
{
  SendMessageToMyQueue();
UpdateStatusInDbThatMessageWasSent();
tr.Compleate();
}
```

will be guaranteed that there will be a lock on `MyQueue` created and this lock will be not released until `UpdateStatusInDbThatMessageWasSent` will update the status?

also if I add try catch with rollback and updating status fails, will the message be removed from `MyQueue` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as lock on a queue. The message, however, will be processed transactionally, if the following conditions are met. By transactionally, I mean that the message will be returned to the queue if an unhandled exception is thrown. The conditions to make this happen are:

- Your database can enlist and take part in a distributed transaction. Not every database out there does. Some Document databases have none (in case of MongoDB) or sketchy (in case of RavenDB) support for DTC.
- Your transport also supports distributed transactions. If you go with a broker type transports, SQL Server Transport is your best bet and on Bus type transports MSMQ is a good choice. Transports like Azure ServiceBus or RabbitMQ have very limited transactions support and do not support distributed transactions.
- You'll need to run Distributed Transaction Coordinator service configured and running.

Two other things to note:

- What if you're using a transport that lacks DTC support? Most of the time, you are better off if you can design your system to be [idempotent](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2013/06/03/un-reliability-in-messaging-idempotency-and-de-duplication/). [Outbox](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/outbox/?version=core_7) feature of NServiceBus allows you simulate DTC to some extent.
- When a message is picked from the queue, processed, and returned to the queue due to an exception, it might end up being in a different place in the queue. You need to [design for messages arriving out of order](http://udidahan.com/2007/12/15/handling-messages-out-of-order/) when designing a message-based architecture.

With all said above, [exactly-once delivery guarantees](http://bravenewgeek.com/you-cannot-have-exactly-once-delivery/) are always a hot topic and disputed.